# PHP can include Text/HTML from CGI but not from Text/CSS?

Tags: php

There's no problem to include cgi output with php except when it is Text/CSS. I tried to do so with:

```
<?php echo system('./cgi-bin/stylegallery.cgi'); ?>
```

As you can see here, it returns blank:
http://reboltutorial.com/gallery/stylegallery.php

whereas the cgi is returning something:
http://reboltutorial.com/cgi-bin/stylegallery.cgi

I tried to add content-type:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
<?php echo system('./cgi-bin/stylegallery.cgi'); ?>
```

But nothing changed. Any idea why ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PHP docs, [`system()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) only returns the last line of output from your executed script.

The [`passthru()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) function might be more suited for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Bear in mind that passthru takes a return variable and the function itself returns void. You would have to do something along the lines of:
    $returnvar = '';
    passthru('./cgi-bin/stylegallery.cgi', $returnvar);
    echo $returnvar;

Comment: I don't understand your answer as this works for Text/HTML so that reason would also apply to Text/HTML ?

Now also try passthru maybe it will work better :). Thanks.